# Batch Complete Tasks in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have my Django website where i can have tasks created and subtasks under tasks i have mark complete option which is working fine i need them to be completed in batch like selecting multiple tasks at once and complete them.

**serializers.py**:

```
class TaskCompleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = (
        'is_done',
    )

     def update(self, instance, validated_data):
         person = self.context['request'].user.person

         task_is_done = validated_data.get('is_done', False)

         if task_is_done:
            instance.subtasks.update(is_done=True)

         instance.is_done = task_is_done
         instance.done_by.set([person])
         instance.save()

         return instance
```

**views.py**:

```
class TaskUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
     permission_classes = " "
     serializer_class = TaskCompleteSerializer
     queryset = Task.objects.all()
     model = Task
     lookup_url_kwarg = 'task_id'
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:task_id>/complete/',views.TaskUpdateAPIView.as_view(), 
name='task_update'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Task(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    done_by = models.ManyToManyField(
    User,
    related_name='tasks_completed',
    blank=True,
    )
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: so you want for example, to mark the tasks with id in (1,2,3,4) as completed using just one API?

Comment: @DavidLu Right now i am able to complete the single task i want both functionalities single completion and batch complete as u said i should be able to select multiple id 's and complete them at once

Comment: Is this api authenticated?

Comment: @DavidLu You mean the permission classes?

Comment: Yes, I meant the `permission_classes`

Comment: @DavidLu Yes It does have

Comment: @DavidLu Can't we achieve that in same serializer and view?

Comment: I think `UpdateAPIView` is the detail view and the url was already set with the format like `/<task_id>/complete`. So it's impossible to use this for multiple purposes.

Comment: @DavidLu But different url with same view wouldn't work?

Comment: Of course it works but you already set `lookup_url_kwarg` in the view, so I think the new function api view is needed for that API. You can also avoid confusion and errors.

Comment: @DavidLu But if u see in the Serializer logic we also have subtask which are linked to the tasks i think u missed it in your logic

Comment: What do you mean? You mean, you want to update `request.user.tasks_completed` without uploading task ids?

Comment: no i have other model called subtask which is foreign key to Task subtask_of = models.ForeignKey(
        Task,
        related_name='subtasks',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    ) if u observe we have ***instance.subtasks.update*** in serilaizer

Comment: @DavidLu Can we have the same view without using the serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a function API view to implement this easily.

```
class TaskBulkUpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    task_ids = serializers.ListField(
        child = serializers.IntegerField())
    is_done = serializers.BooleanField()
```

And in views.py, you need to create `bulk_update_tasks` function.

```
from .serializers import TaskBulkUpdateSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .models import Task, Subtask

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def bulk_update_tasks(request):
    serializer = TaskBulkUpdateSerializer(request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        input_data = serializer.validated_data
        task_ids = input_data.get('task_ids')
        is_done = input_data.get('is_done')
        
        # check if all the tasks exist and all of them are owned by the user
        for task_id in task_ids:
            try:
                task = Task.objects.get(pk = task_id)                
                if task.done_by.id != request.user.id:
                    return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            except:
                return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # if it's ok, then update
        Task.objects.filter(id__in = task_ids).update(is_done = is_done)

        # update subtasks
        if is_done:
            Subtask.objects.filter(subtask_of__id__in = task_ids).update(is_done = True)
        
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In urls.py, you need to add the api.

```
path('complete/bulk', bulk_update_task, name='task_bulk_update')
```